# How to prove this polar equation is true plz help

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

[image]

So in the picture above it states that $\tan(\theta) = \dfrac{r}{\tfrac{dr}{d \theta}}$and I’m asked to show that this is true. So what I did was I used the identity $\tan(x) = \sin(x)/\cos(x)$ and so that means $\sin(\theta)= r$ and $r'=\cos(\theta)$. Am I correct cause I have no clue if what I’m doing is even relevant.

Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: You have been around for three months. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: The picture does not state that $\tan\theta=\frac{r}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}}$, it states that $\tan\psi=\frac{r}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}}$. As the hint suggests, maybe use the tangent angle subtraction formula. Also, the general equation $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{a}{b}$ does not imply that $x=a$ and $y=b$.

Comment: Do you have any tools introduced in the chapter that can help you with this problem? Perhaps something involving calculating the slope of the tangent line to polar graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we want to do is to make everything as polar coordinates, e.g. $r, \theta, \frac{dr}{d\theta}$, etc. But $\tan\phi=\frac{dy}{dx}$ which makes it something of $x$ and $y$. So having observed that we want to prove $\tan\psi=\frac{r}{dr/d\theta}$, which contains a derivative with respect to $\theta$, we use the identity $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy/d\theta}{dx/d\theta}$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, $x=r\cos\theta$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\sin\theta+r\cos\theta}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos\theta-r\sin\theta}$. Then $$\tan\psi=\tan(\phi-\theta)\\=\frac{\tan\phi-\tan\theta}{1+\tan{\phi}\tan\theta}\\=\frac{\frac{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\sin\theta+r\cos\theta}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos\theta-r\sin\theta}-\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}{1+\frac{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\sin^2\theta+r\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos^2\theta-r\sin\theta\cos\theta}}\\=\frac{\frac{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\sin\theta\cos\theta+r\cos^2\theta-\frac{dr}{d\theta}\sin\theta\cos\theta+r\sin^2\theta}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos^2\theta-r\sin\theta\cos\theta}}{\frac{\frac{dr}{d\theta}}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos^2\theta-r\sin\theta\cos\theta}}\\=\frac{r}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}}$$.